# Access passthrough query to Oracle without VBA

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc

Is there any way to send a passthrough query to Oracle from Access, and have Oracle return the record set without using the Jet engine or VBA?  I need to execute a query against a view and not have Access process the WHERE condition.  I'd prefer to stay away from VBA because it gets ugly from a user perspective.  I do know how to do it with VBA and an ADO connection string passthrough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind guys, I found my own answer.

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tutorials/passthrough/basics01.php